# Using transform and plyr to add a counting column in R

Tags: r, plyr

I have a two-level dataset (let's say classes nested within schools) and the dataset was coded

Like this:

```
School  Class
  A       1
  A       1
  A       2
  A       2
  B       1
  B       1
  B       2
  B       2
```

But to run an analysis I need the data to have a unique Class ID, regardless of school membership.

```
School  Class  NewClass
  A       1       1
  A       1       1
  A       2       2
  A       2       2
  B       1       3
  B       1       3
  B       2       4
  B       2       4
```

I tried using transform and ddply, but I'm not sure how to keep NewClass continually incrementing to a larger number for each combination of School and Class. I can think of a few inelegant ways to do this, but I'm sure there are much easy solutions I just can't think of right now. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `interaction` to create a factor, and then coerce it to integer:

```
transform(dat,nn = as.integer(interaction(Class,School)))
  School Class nn
1      A     1  1
2      A     1  1
3      A     2  2
4      A     2  2
5      B     1  3
6      B     1  3
7      B     2  4
8      B     2  4
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dt = as.data.table(your_df)

dt[, NewClass := .GRP, by = list(School, Class)]
dt
#   School Class NewClass
#1:      A     1        1
#2:      A     1        1
#3:      A     2        2
#4:      A     2        2
#5:      B     1        3
#6:      B     1        3
#7:      B     2        4
#8:      B     2        4
```

`.GRP` is simply a group counter. Also note that you don't really need to do this and can keep using the above combination `list(School, Class)` in whatever `by` operation you need to do.

---

Note that from data.table versions `>= 1.9.0`, a function `setDT` is exported that converts a `data.frame` to `data.table` by reference (no copy is made), in case you'd want to stick to data.tables.

```
require(data.table) ## >= 1.9.0
setDT(your_df)      ## your_df is now a data.table, changed by reference.
```

Comment: @Arun thanks, I need to add that to my vocabulary (also I think you meant *now instead of not)